# Does when using dynamic framework increase binary size than using static framework?

Tags: ios, cocoapods, static-libraries, static-linking, dynamic-linking

This is iOS & Cocoapods question.

My iOS App launching speed was too slow.
So, to reduce the dylib loading time, I changed the dynamic frameworks in Pods to static frameworks by using [cocoapods-static-frameworks](https://github.com/b-ray/cocoapods-static-frameworks).

And then,
as I wanted, reduced the app launch time and everything work well as before.
However, unexpectedly the app's binary size has been reduced 20MB. (80MB to 60MB)

Does when using dynamic framework increase binary size than using static framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it dose, because dynamic frameworks only links what you actually need.

"When dynamic libraries are linked, none of the library's code is included directly into the linked target. Instead, the libraries are loaded into memory at runtime prior to having symbols getting resolved."